# How to get pivot table sheet last fill row number using POI + Java. -version 3.12.x

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have one Excel sheet which contains two sheets. One is a Data sheet and the second is a pivot sheet.

I have an issue while getting the last row number in the Excel sheet which  contains the pivot table.
I am using -version 3.12.x poi.

I tried `areaRef.getLastCell().getCol();`, `newSheet.getLastRowNum();` and `pivotTable.getDataSheet().getPhysicalNumberOfRows()` and other existing methods also. 
But I'm not getting the correct value. Its returning the Data sheet last number of record instead of pivot sheet.

Does anybody know how to get last fill row number in pivot table sheet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got my solution. Instead of going through last row number i used footer object.